# Find time taken by codeigniter views to render

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am loading 3 views in CI controller. How may i compute the time taken by all the three views to render completely? Any help?

Comment: Why not use `microtime` or similar; get time before Render, get time after render and compute difference?

Comment: Yes. That is useful.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of the built in [Profling](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html?highlight=profiling) CI has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Codeigniter Native function

Place it in your footer OR end of the page

```
<strong>Page Execution Time {elapsed_time}</strong>
```

Read more here from Codeigniter Docs [Benchmarking Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html)

Comment: @KiranNSone if Answer has worked don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you can use `microtime` or similar to do so:

1. First, get time before Render
2. Then proceed to render
3. Finally, get time after render and compute difference